# Javascript to close browser window simultaneously with dialog box

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm working on an asp.net web form. This form has a button to open a new window (report window) and show a report. But first the user has to select a client from the list in the form before he/she can see the report. For validation matter, I use code to check whether the user has selected one of the client or not, the validation is done in the new window (report window).
The validation is set to show a javascript dialog box if the user hasn't selected one of the client, it's working fine, the dialog box show the message with a single **OK** button. Is it possible to close the window concurrent with the dialog box when the user click the **OK** button ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not with an alert window (you cannot get the event when the user clicks ok), you need either

- a confirm instead of an alert so you can react on the event
- or a "self-made" dialog like jquery dialog http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/ there you can react on the click event

And then just close the window with window.close()

Comment: thx for confirming this, I finally decided to validate it at the main form.